# Record an outbound call in twillio

Tags: twilio

I am trying to record an outbound call using [twillio php code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-record-phone-calls-php) :

Once i execute the code in browser, call will go to destination number [+919999999999].

**Issue** :

but once it recieved, some default voice will play and call will be disconnected....

**Requirement** :

But i want both pepoles [ source & destination ] should speak and want to record that conversation....

```
<?php

require_once '/var/www/html/ecom1/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "account_sid";
$token  = "auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create("+919999999999",
                        "+918888888888",
                        array(
                            "record" => True,
                            "url" => "http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=%2B918888888888&"

                        )
               );

print($call->sid);
?>
```

I am using Trail account....

Comment: What does the default voice say? Is it an error message ("An error has occurred") or something else?

Comment: @philnash thanks for reply , There is `play` button in dashboard, once i click on that, nothing plays.....

Comment: So, wait, your calls are being connected correctly? But the issue is with the recording?

Comment: @philnash you are right.....

Comment: Please don't publish your account sid and auth token! They can be used by anyone to drain your account. I recommend that you log into your Twilio account and request a new auth token.

Comment: @philnash i am using trial account, so i thought thats not a problem....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174620/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-philnash).

Comment: thanks @philnash for your time & help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the parameter **"Record=true"** when making a POST request to tell Twilio to record an outgoing call via the REST API.

By default, the recording will be single-channel (mono). For dual-channel recordings (two legs of the call each in separate stereo channels), append the parameter "**RecordingChannels=dual**".

```
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install 
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library 

use Twilio\Rest\Client; 

$account_sid = '<account_sid value>'; 
$auth_token = '<auth_token value>'; 
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$calls = $client->accounts("<account id>") 
  ->calls->create("<Valid To number>", "<Valid From number>", array(   
        'Method' => "POST",         
        'Record' => "true", 
        'RecordingChannels' => "dual" 
  ));
```

**Please Note :**

When attempt to initiate an outbound phone call, ensure the URL you specified to handle the call should be valid URL.

If you specified an Application Sid for your outbound phone call, the application must have a valid VoiceUrl or the call will fail.

Hope this information helps you !

Comment: now i am trying [link](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-php/blob/1.4/index.html)   , it gave `Error - 11200 `
HTTP retrieval failure , here is image : https://prnt.sc/k4bh77

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200   - this link has possible root cause and solution given